# how to create SQL Server Database with vb.net code

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express, localdb

I'm using VB 2012 and SQL Server 2012 Localdb

I want to create a database file (`.mdf`) in my folder `C:\AppData`

eg. db file name `0105.mdf` & log file name `0105.ldf`

Can anyone please tell me the procedure?

I can connect to SQL Server 2012 localdb using connection string

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename={0};Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Steve Pettifer

Here is final code which worked

```
        Dim Conn As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")
        Using Conn
            Conn.Open()
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = Conn.CreateCommand
            Dim str As String = "CREATE Database {0} ON (Name= N'{0}', FileName='{1}\{0}.mdf')"
            cmd.CommandText = String.Format(str, T2.Text, T1.Text)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
```

T1.text : Folder Location
T2.text : File Name without extention

Comment: Ah cool, you just beat me to my edit :) Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 2):

Use SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Dim queryString As String = "CREATE DATABASE [0105] ON  PRIMARY (NAME = N'0105', FILENAME = N'C:\APPDATA\Pluto_Data.MDF' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB ) " & _
                                "LOG ON (NAME = N'0105_Log', FILENAME = N'C:\APPDATA\0105_Log.LDF' , SIZE = 1024KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 1024KB )"

    Using connection As New SqlConnection(queryString)
        Dim command As New SqlCommand(queryString, connection)
        command.Connection.Open()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
```

Just change the bits you need to change above like the filegroup, file growth and initial sizes etc. I think that'll work although I haven't got LocalDB to hand to try it so I may be a bit off course.

### **EDIT:** I was off course and too free and easy with the T-SQL.

Try this instead, from the link I added in a comment below.

```
Public Function CreateDatabase(ByVal dbName As String, ByVal dbFileName As String) As Boolean

    Try

        Dim connectionString As String = String.Format("Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True")
        Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString))

            connection.Open()
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = connection.CreateCommand()


            DetachDatabase(dbName)

            cmd.CommandText = String.Format("CREATE DATABASE {0} ON (NAME = N'{0}', FILENAME = '{1}')", dbName, dbFileName)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using

        If (My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(dbFileName)) Then
            Return True
        Else
            Return False
        End If

    Catch
        Throw
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: err **Keyword not supported: 'create database [0105] on  primary (name'.**

Comment: ah there we go - the dangers of not having it to hand to test!

Comment: There is a demo [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/268c3411-102a-4272-b305-b14e29604313/localdb-create-connect-to-database-programmatically-?forum=sqlsetupandupgrade). It is in C# but you could easily convert it to VB. It doesn't look that different to what I suggested - I think I got a bit free and easy with the options you use on full SQL Server.